# Como manejar imagenes en una API Rest (Con Spring Boot)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, imagen

Lo que quiero preguntar es como se deberían manejar las imágenes en una API Rest en este caso con Spring Boot, tendría estas dudas:

- Que datos de la imagen debería de enviarme el Fronted (Hecho con React js) para guardar la esta (Teniendo en cuenta que la comunicación es vía JSON)
- Una vez recibida como la debería manejar desde el endPoint usaria las clases File de java de alguna manera o ¿como?.
- Al intentar guardarla en la Base de Datos que debería de almacenar y de que tipo seria el campo en el sql.

Actualmente y manejo el guardado de imágenes de esta forma:

- El Fronted transforma la imagen en un String en base 64.
- El endPoint es un POST, que recibe en el body el String, con un campo como este

```java
@Lob
private String photo;
```

La anotación Lob vi que servía para indicarle que este campo recibirá información mas pesada de lo normal como puede ser una imagen.

- Luego lo guardo en la base de datos como String, el tipo de campo que uso para recibir el String en mysql es "MEDIUMTEXT".

Actualmente lo hago de esa manera, se que no es lo mejor, pero, cual es la manera correcta o mas optima de guardar una imagen para una API Rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma genérica:

1. Principalmente necesitas dos parámetros: el nombre original del archivo (con su exención) y el string base64. Por ejemplo:

```json
{
  "fileName":"archivo.jpeg", 
  "fileBase64":"..."
}
```

2. Al recibir la petición primero debes decodificar el base64 y luego almacenar el binario en algún directorio del disco. [Escribir Base64 imagen a archivo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879639/write-base64-encoded-image-to-file)
3. En la base de datos registras solo la ruta donde se almaceno el archivo en dos campos de tipo string (varchar), uno para la ruta y otro para el nombre del archivo. Ejemplo: `/tmp/photos/` y `archivo.jpeg`. Luego puedes usar este dato para recuperar el archivo desde el disco.

```sql
CREATE TABLE photos (
    id int,
    path varchar,
    name varchar
);
```

Comment: Y que pasa, si el front me envía el nombre de un archivo que ya se ha creado?              Ejemplo: envía archivo.jpg y luego vuelve a enviar archivo.jpg,  Que hago en esa situación porque estaría sobrescribiendo uno o no?

Comment: En el punto 2, al almacenar el archivo en disco, puedes modificar su nombre por un nombre único. Por ejemplo agregando un `timestamp` de la forma `1662564445_archivo.jpeg`. Si quieres conservar el nombre original puedes registrarlo en un campo de la base de datos.